# How can I use pseudoproperties in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

[From the documentation:](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_fields_and_properties)

> By convention, Groovy will recognize properties even if there is no
> backing field provided there are getters or setters that follow the
> Java Beans specification. For example:

```
class PseudoProperties {
  void setName(String name) {}
  String getName() {} 
} 
def p = new PseudoProperties() 
p.name = 'Foo'
```

> **This syntactic sugar is at the core of many DSLs written in Groovy.**

I noticed that if we declare a pseudo property as a class method, then we can refer to this property through a dot `person.name`. But we can't not save the value into it, not get it.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def person = new Person();
        println "before: ${person.properties.get('name')}"
        person.name = "10"
        println "after: ${person.properties.get('name')}"
    }
}

class Person {
    void setName(String name) {}
    String getName() {return ""} //TODO ????
}
```

I don't fully understand why then pseudo properties like this are needed? So that you can simply call the method through a dot? And how can such pseudo properties help in creating a DSL on a groove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a name, and then get it with `getName`, you will need a backing field (and not a pseudoproperty).

All pseudoproperties are is that if you have a method

```
String getWhoIsCool() { 
   "Tim" 
}
```

then you can access it with the property access notation `obj.whoIsCool` (you don't need to call the getter method)